# Do we still need more questions?

Tags: discussion

When looking at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage) we can see that we have quite few questions per day. Should we put more effort in filling the site with content by asking questions? Will this help the site to grow? Would it al all be possible to shape the content we want this site to have by not only answering, commenting, or close voting, but also by asking questions?

I am asking this because now once too often when I did ask a question it was frowned upon with me being overtly accused of artificially pushing the site:

> Relax, Takkat. Questions will come or they won't. Pump-priming won't make a difference. [Link](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6057/wann-heisst-es-nutzniesser-niessnutzer-oder-niessbraucher-und-wann-genuss#comment16332_6057)

Because of this I had already dramatically reduced my asking questions here. But sometimes I still have a question where I really would like to hear other's opinions. Obviously I would have no problem at all to stop asking in these cases too.

But what reason could there be that avid users should stop asking?

Comment: It depends. I partly agree to splattne. In case of your question from this morning, I'd say this question is not interesting to many people. I even don't know these words (except of the common saying *in den Genuß kommen*) which I consider to have a **completely different connotation**, at least that is what my 2 minute Google search told me. I might be wrong but anyway, I was already voting for close as not constructive but haven't done for different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's perfectly okay to create content posting new questions – as long as the questions are interesting and make sense.

From the [German Stackexchange FAQ](https://german.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Stack Exchange is for speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation.

The keyword here is *discuss*. We're not only allowed, we're encouraged to use this site as a place to live our language nerds' life. ;-)

Also, looking at the score of your questions, there's evidence that many other users find your questions interesting and stimulating.

So yes, please go on!